# Python Flask:Why dose the logging IP & mobile phone IP different?

Tags: python, flask

i need to get the IP address of UE(User Equipment) in my webapp created with Python&Flask.
i am using request.remote_addr and request.headers library.
but obtained IP is different from my mobile phone's real IP address.

eg.
obtained IP from my web app : xxx.xxx.xxx.158

My phone's IP : xxx.xxx.xxx.195

(but it works correctly in my PC)

wep app's code is below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/get_my_ip", methods=["GET"])
def get_my_ip():
   return request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-For', request.remote_addr)
```

any fix to that?

Comment: Can you share the first octet of the IP?s Is one of the addresses in the LAN space?

Comment: @MattClark My mobile phone's first octet is "106".

Comment: my web app server is in Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: web server's first octet is "35"

Comment: I think we need a bit more info to help you answer this.  Is your phone on your wifi, or on your mobile provider?  It may be an extra caching proxy between you and the server that you are unaware of, especially if it's just http (non-https).  Also, for all the IP's you are using, if you aren't going to share the IPs with us, at least go lookup who owns those ips, eg: https://www.ultratools.com/tools/geoIp as this will inform you as to where that IP that you aren't accounting for came from.  It's possibly a load balancer/proxy/etc.

Comment: @Farley my phone is on mobile provider. not on wifi. ultratools.com result is 106.xxx.xxx.109. but my web app's logging result is 106.xxx.xxx.158 yet.

Comment: when comparing IP through a PC browser, the result is same.based on these result, i think one of the mobile phone's IP result is the IP of base station....